# Перемешивание массива в PHP

Tags: php

Как перемешать массив случайным образом. Чтобы с каждым разом вызова скрипта массив был разным?

Comment: Некоторое время пытался понять первую фразу.

Comment: "отсортировать ... на пофиг" = "перемешать"  
Учите русский, а?!

Comment: Всё нормально, я же понял.

Comment: "все говорят фильм для дураков, а мне понравился" (с)

Answer (score 6):

В этом Вам поможет прекрасная функция [`shuffle`()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shuffle.php), мы все знаем насколько она хороша, её использование вызывает фантастическое удовольствие.

Answer (score -3):

Сортировать большой массив долго, если ключи последовательно - нужно сгенерировать случайные цифры в диапазоне ключей и выдать эти элементы.

Comment: Цифры -- это числа от "0" до "9". Вы хотели сказать "число" наверное, а не "цифра". А если ключи не последовательно? А если ключ - не число, а строка? А если не надо выдавать элементы, а лишь сформировать другой массив - то не будет ли ещё дольше, чем встроенная функция `shuffle`? В общем, ужасный ответ, не добавивший ничего нового и полезного. Верный ответ про `shuffle` уже выдали, еще несколько лет назад.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Слишком много если, при такой неопределённости правильного ответа быть не может. При большом массиве с последовательными ключами (если они не последовательны - сделайте их последовательными) сгенерировать случайные индексы в нём и выдать эти элементы будет быстрее чем пересортировать его. Попробуйте написать оба алгоритма на языке подразумевающем работу с памятью - это станет очевидно. Пшп скрывает от нас эту работу, но не скроет время которое на неё должно быть затрачено.